# Export XML from filemaker, encoding problems

Tags: xml, utf-8, filemaker

One of our customers exports an xml file from filemaker using FMPXMLRESULTS which we use to import product information to a website. This used to work fine but now the import of the XML document failed. After inspecting the XML file we discovered that the encoding of the file is MacRoman but the first line in XML says it is UTF-8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Is there an option in FileMaker to export to UTF-8 instead of MacRoman? Are there other things that could change the file encoding?

Thanks,
Martijn

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange. FileMaker XML export is fairly accurate with encoding. I never saw it doing something like that and I work with FM XML a lot. What is the FileMaker version? How have you determined that the encoding is actually MacRoman, not UTF-8? Does the customer use the export command (maybe they compose the XML as text and write to file)?

Anyway, the raw export uses fixed UTF-8, but, of course, it must possible to change this with a XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="THIS FILE ENCODING"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="XSL NAMESPACE">
  <output encoding="TARGET ENCODING" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```